# Which United States cities started getting electricity in the 1920s?

Tags: united-states

In the 1920s, electricity was starting to expand to rural and urban communities. What exact cities got electricity during that decade (more specifically, 1920-1929)

Comment: This is kind of a borderline question because it is trivia, not really a question of vital historical importance. Nevertheless, I will vote to leave it open because economic history is somewhat neglected, so I think for genuine questions concerning economic history there should be a lower bar.

Answer (score 1):

The 1920s was when rural areas and smaller urban areas started to get electricity. All major cities had electricty long before then. The minor cities and towns electrified in the 20s are probably too numerous to list.

http://www.oregon.gov/oprd/HCD/OHC/docs/archambault_rural_electric_0410.pdf

The electrical revolution had begun; and like no other force in history, electricity completely transformed how  people lived.  By turn of the century, residents of every major city in America were enjoying its benefits.  In fact, its distribution and application in cities was so universal and met such basic needs that  it became an absolute necessity for modern life.3   By the 1930s, however, the failure to electrify the whole country had deprived the  millions of people who  lived in rural areas of the convenience of a modern standard of living.  For nearly half  a century while urban Americans enjoyed the pleasures of electricity, rural Americans continued to toil in darkness.